# Find with multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

"I'm importing records from a CSV file and need to check for existing records before adding. The problem is I don't have any IDs in the file.

Here are the models:

```
class Shooter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shooters
  has_many :scores
end

class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shooter
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Here is my import method:

```
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      # some_how_find_duplicates_here...
      score.attributes = row.to_hash
      score.save!
    end
  end
```

I'm guessing I need to search with names and do something like:

```
score = Score.where("shooter.name == row.shooter_name & event.name == row.event_name") || new
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: which is the unique field ?

Comment: At this stage I'm validating uniqueness on shooter.name and event.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating objects then search for duplicates then remove , why don't you filter the `CSV` inputs from the beginning, specially if it's not a huge file

Since `CSV` row is an array, we can stack rows in an `Array` of arrays and use [uniq](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21) to filter the duplicate rows out:

```
def self.import(file)
  rows = []
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    rows << row      
  end
  # remove out duplicates
  rows.uniq!

  #now create objects
  rows.each do |row|
    score.attributes = row.to_hash
    score.save!
  end
end
```

**Note:**

**[Uniq](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21)** accepts a block to explain how uniqueness is checked (e.g by first column only of the row -- check the api docs link for more details)

example from the docs:

```
c = [["student","sam"], ["student","george"], ["teacher","matz"]]
c.uniq! { |s| s.first } # => [["student", "sam"], ["teacher", "matz"]]
```

## Update

Since the comparison should be done with database records, we make a small mofication to the code above:

```
def self.import(file)
  rows = []
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    rows << row      
  end
  # remove out duplicates
  rows.reject! {|row| Score.where("shooter_name = ? AND event_name = ?",row[shooter_name_col_no],row[event_name_col_no]).any?}

  #now create objects
  rows.each do |row|
    score.attributes = row.to_hash
    score.save!
  end
end
```

Here we use [**reject!**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) which will remove rows if the block argument returned `true`. Now you should obviously modify with correct attributes names and row column numbers for this to work.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself properly. I need to check the database for existing scores. i.e. a shooter can only have one score per event.